# IIS renders embedded font icons incorrectly

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts, iis-7

I have a static web page that displays icons embedded in one of the css references. The icons are not displayed properly and we see some junk characters instead when browsed to from IIS. The same web page when opened directly in the browser seems to render fine. I wonder if it is some misconfiguration in the static page website but I am unable to figure out what the issue could be. Would greatly appreciate any help to solve this issue.

[The page when rendered by IIS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHwTB.png)

[The page when rendered by browser directly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVh0k.png)

Looks like the CSS file is the issue.
[The css file when browsed to via IIS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKkFj.png)

[The original css file opened with the browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrU0a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use extended styles and sass syntax, when SASS does the compression, it changes Font Awesome characters from escaped ASCII sequences to unicode. So you need to add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the head to let the browser know how to interpret it.